# SELECT query with apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have a column named `storeName` with a value called `Joe's Kitchen`.

When user enters Joe's Kitchen, I would store it in a variable named `storeName` and do a select query on it like this: `"SELECT * FROM shops WHERE storename='".$storeName."'"`. Problem now is that the value contains apostrophe, how should I go about this ?

I have tried the method below but it is not working

```
$storeName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->getConnection(),$_POST["storeName"]);
```

Comment: use prepared statement to insert

Answer (score 0):

Escape the apostrophe in query by writing two apostrophes 
Example

```
    SELECT * FROM shops WHERE storename='Joe''s Kitchen'  //added 2 apostrophes
```

> this is not a recommended method since it has serious security issues, try to use pdo or parameterized queries

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, you can replace the single quote ' by `. Then the name can contain single quotes...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE    
storename="Joe\'s Kitchen"
```

Comment: You should rather answer in the duplicate.